# Use .htaccess to rewrite URL with GET variables

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to make my url of:

```
example.com/index.php?this=a&that=b
```

to:

```
example.com/index.php/a/b
```

So that whenever somebody visits this page directly:

```
example.com/index.php/a/b
```

It will display in the address bar as typed, but will render the content for:

```
example.com/index.php?this=a&that=b
```

How is that done?

Comment: When will people start to read documentations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^index\.php/([^/]+?)/(.+)/?$ index.php?this=$1&that=$2 [L,NC]
```